# Using one set of ROIs to classify multiple raster layers in ENVI?

Tags: classification, envi

I am attempting to run a SAM classification on an airborne hyperspectral dataset with six total flight lines, and the files are too large to mosaic before processing. Is it possible to create an automated workflow that uses one set of ROIs with multiple classes taken from all the raster layers to then use for classifying each raster individually?

I'm quite new to ENVI and have never used the API before, but I have seen some things about a tile iterator. Is it possible to use this?

Comment: Could you share those 'things' you saw about the tile iterator? It would help us understand your problem on what you want to do.

Comment: Here's what I found: https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/programmingguidetileiterators.html

Comment: From what I understand, this is used to process one large dataset in many small pieces, which can then be merged after. I want to process six large raster datasets (essentially already in tile form as they have not been mosaiced) but use the same process and set of ROIs for each one. Does this make sense? My main problem is that I cannot find a way to create a set of ROIs from multiple layers, so I can't train a classification that covers the entire area.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something here, but how can you use the same ROIs for different tiles? Maybe you can define your ROIs and perform classification on the first tile, then define another set of ROIs for the second tile and perform classification etc

Comment: I agree it's the simpler option, but I'm doing a spectral angle mapper classification, so it would be good to use ROIs from across the whole area for consistency. Ideally I would just merge all the layers, pick my ROIs across the whole area and run it, but it's too big. Sorry if this is confusing, I feel I'm making it more complicated than it should be but I just want to maintain the consistency of classification across the whole area by using the same derived spectral signatures for the classes, which would require the same set of ROIs. Does that make sense?